How should I correctly configure tasks when using sockets in python?
I have this small snippet which I intend to have function as a server, I have managed to get the socket to connect to the client but cannot send data due to errors.
import asyncio
import json
import socketio
from aiohttp import web

ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:45100"]

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins=ALLOWED_ORIGINS)
app = web.Application()#socketio.ASGIApp(sio)
sio.attach(app)

@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    origin=environ.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', '')
    if origin not in ALLOWED_ORIGINS:
        print(f'Connection from {origin} imetupwa')
        await sio.disconnect(sid)

    else:
        print(f'Allowing connection from {origin}')

@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    print('Disconnected', sid)

async def send_gpio_data():
    print('Going to send data')
    try:
        while True:
            data = {'speed': 100}
            await sio.emit('ecuData', json.dumps(data))
            print("Data sent, sleeping...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'Error in sending data: {error}')

async def main():
    print('Init main')
    asyncio.create_task(send_gpio_data())

    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, '0.0.0.0', 8090)
    print("Web app running on http://0.0.0.0:8090")
    await site.start()

    await asyncio.Event().wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Done!")

Here is the putout:
Init main
Web app running on http://0.0.0.0:8090
Going to send data
Data sent, sleeping...
Allowing connection from http://localhost:45100
Error in sending data: Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.
/Users/keronei/StudioProjects/Side Projects/rotor/server.py:35: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncServer._emit_internal' was never awaited
  print(f'Error in sending data: {error}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

The execution stops right after the crash, I have also tried  sio.start_background_task(send_gpio_data) but I get the same error.

Is the version of your code posted in your question simplified in any way from the original code? The error suggests there is more going on in your application than what is shown in the code.

I found the problem to be an incompatible asyncio with Python version.
On a random search, someone responded to the same issue on Medium with the following comment, I presume the commenter is a maintainer/contributor:

...but for this error, I suspect that it's because the Python version I've used for the template was below 3.11. For me, I used 3.10. Could you downgrade the Python version (by creating another virtualenv) and try it out with a different version?

From this, I re-created the virtual environment with Python 3.9 and the error went away.
This is just a fix, but there should be a correct approach for Python 3.10 and up.
If curious, here is what I did (on Mac):

Checked the versions of Python that are installed

which -a python python3

This returns a list of installation locations, I picked each of them (to figure out if there was 3.10 or below)
$ /usr/local/bin/python3

This opens a Python environment with the version indicated.

I deleted and created a new virtual environment:

virtualenv  -p /usr/bin/python3 env 

I then activated and ran the script and the error was gone.

import asyncio
import json
import socketio
from aiohttp import web

ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:45100"]

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins=ALLOWED_ORIGINS)
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    origin = environ.get('HTTP_ORIGIN', '')
    if origin not in ALLOWED_ORIGINS:
        print(f'Connection from {origin} rejected')
        await sio.disconnect(sid)
    else:
        print(f'Allowing connection from {origin}')

@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    print('Disconnected', sid)

async def send_gpio_data():
    print('Going to send data')
    try:
        while True:
            data = {'speed': 100}
            await sio.emit('ecuData', data)  # No need to json.dumps, just send dict
            print("Data sent, sleeping...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'Error in sending data: {error}')

async def main():
    print('Init main')
    # Schedule the coroutine to run in the background
    sio.start_background_task(send_gpio_data)

    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, '0.0.0.0', 8090)
    print("Web app running on http://0.0.0.0:8090")
    await site.start()

    await asyncio.Event().wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Done!")


Ensure Task Scheduling: Use asyncio.create_task correctly to schedule the coroutine. In your main function, you should be using asyncio.create_task or sio.start_background_task to schedule the send_gpio_data coroutine. Ensure that this coroutine is properly awaited or scheduled as a background task.
Await Correctly: The error message indicates that the coroutine sio.emit('ecuData', json.dumps(data)) was not awaited properly. Ensure that you await all asynchronous calls within your coroutine. In your case, sio.emit should be awaited correctly to avoid the RuntimeWarning.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
